# why do while loops that are supposed to be infinite terminate if supplied with even numbers in Java

Tags: java

Ok, here is my problem. When I initialize `x` with `5`, the while loop doesn't terminate but initializing it with an even number such as `6` terminates the loop:

```
int x = 6;
while(x != 0){
    x = x + 2;
}
```

Surprisingly for me, this terminates even though I thought it would not. However,the following similar loop, with odd value for x loops infinitely:

```
int x = 5
while(x != 0){
    x += 2;
}
```

It seems this happens only with the `while` loop in Java as I didn't get similar results with the `for` loop. Please help explain this to me as I'm currently confused. Thanks

Comment: Integer overflow.

Comment: integer overflow and java does not throw an exception in such case... same should happen with `for` loops too (assuming same starting value, condition and increment)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can see the same effect on a regular 12 hour wall clock. Pick any hour. Until you reach 12, add two hours.

You'll notice that if you start on an even hour, you'll always stop. For example, 6:

```
6 + 2  = 8
8 + 2  = 10
10 + 2 = 12  // stop
```

However, if you start on an odd hour, you'll never stop. For example:

```
5 + 2  = 7
7 + 2  = 9
9 + 2  = 11
11 + 2 = 1
1 + 2  = 3
3 + 2  = 5
5 + 2  = 7
...
```

A Java `int` works the same way, but instead of 12 hours, it has 2^32 = 4294967296 values. Instead of wrapping from 12 to 1, it wraps from 2147483647 to -2147483648.

Note that `for` loops *do* behave the same way: `for(int x=6; x!=0; x+=2) {}` does indeed stop while `x=5` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Integer overflows at 2147483647 and if you add 1, it will goes to -2147483648 . So when you start from even number you will get back to zero again. But when you start from odd number you will never get back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to much into depth here, but its because of the overflow. An integer is 32 bit, so its a finite amount of numbers. Since its signed it means that the numbers range from −2.147.483.648 to 2.147.483.647. So in this example: 2.147.483.647 + 1 = -2.147.483.648 is an overflow.

This means if u have x+1 in your while loop will always terminate. Because once the 0 is reached, the while loop condition is broken. If you add 2 it seems to work because the number x reaches 0 at some point.

Hope it helps mate.

Comment: 1) no exception or error on overflow; 2) adding 2 and starting with even number (to reach zero)